# how can i replace or mask a substring before a character in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) with some columns where one called `df['text]` has different strings and some rows have an email.

```
df = df[df['text'].str.contains('@')]['text']
```

I saw a lot of examples like these:

```
Input                      Output
'example@gmail.com'        'exa****@gmail.com'
'example@gmail.com'        '*******@gmail.com'
```

But i  need some more specific like this

```
Input                                                       Output
'My email is example@gmail.com and my name is Fernando'     'My email is exa****@gmail.com and my name is Fernando
```

Sorry for my bad english, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple pattern that replaces at most `3` non-space characters preceding `@` with `***`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['My email is example@gmail.com and my name is Fernando',
             'This email has two characters: ab@gmail.com']
})

df.text.str.replace('(\S{,3}@)', '***@')
```

Output:

```
0    My email is exam***@gmail.com and my name is F...
1         This email has two characters: ***@gmail.com
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works perfect, Quang. Thanks a lot.
is a regular expression, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a regex.